# Magento 2 - wrap everything in a div

Tags: magento2, layout, template, magento-2.1, containers

I need to wrap all my content in a div. I'm trying to add a container w/o any success. I created a child theme and a `custom-home.xml` config file as follow:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="empty"/>

    <container name="panel" as="panel" label="panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel" htmlId="panel" after="body">
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="ves-slideshow" as="ves-slideshow" label="Page Slideshow Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="ves-slideshow clearfix" before="main.content"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </container>

</layout>
```

the container with `name="panel"` does not show up. What am I misunderstading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to move the default container inside your new container.

I would try something like this:

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>

    <container name="panel" as="panel" label="panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel" htmlId="panel" after="body" />
    <move element="page.wrapper" destination="panel" /> 

    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="ves-slideshow" as="ves-slideshow" label="Page Slideshow Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="ves-slideshow clearfix" before="main.content"/>
    </referenceContainer>    
</layout>
```

Comment: how to wrap main content with custom div above it?